# why my bib file does not work

Tags: natbib

I am using TexMaker on linux 18.04 and have problems with the references of my project. I have the project in different folders and all packages are listed in preamble. I wrote the bib file in JabRef and saved it in the  under the name tsample.bib.

When I compile the main.tex file I get an empty References section in the PDF and in the text is cited [?,p.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\title{Bibliography: \texttt{natbib} package}
\author{Minimal Working Example}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of \texttt{natbib} package. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \citet{einstein}, and the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

%Imports the bibliography file "sample.bib"

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Can you compile a small Minimal Working Example (MWE) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that recreates the problem? Having a whole example that recreates the problem at our end would help you get answers from the community much faster

Comment: Press F11, wait a bit, press F6, wait a bit, press F6 again.

Comment: I suspect there's no `\bibliographystyle` in the file, but we can only know when we get a MWE

Comment: Have you run the compilation at least twice? Do you have errors during the compilation?

Comment: The sample document you posted does in no sense resemble the information you have given earlier. *Does that sample document work for you?*

Comment: Thank you  this comment helped me : Press F11, wait a bit, press F6, wait a bit, press F6 again

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer was simply to compile properly